# Como fazer para trabalhar com "dados" LONG inseridos em uma editText?

Tags: java, android, edittext

Tentei passar números que seriam inseridos em 3 editTexts para 3 variáveis **long** que criei: `l01, l02, l03`. Para dessa forma trabalhar eles e fazer uma conta bem simples.

MainActivity.java:

```
package genesysgeneration.treerule;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText et01, et02, et03;
    private TextView tv01;
    private long l01, l02, l03;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        l01=0;
        l02=0;
        l03=0;

        et01=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et01);
        et02=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et02);
        et03=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et03);

        l01=et01;
        l02=et02;
        l03=et03;

        tv01=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv01);
        tv01.setText(l01*l02*l03);

    }
}
```

Eu também mudei o 3 inputType dos 3 editTexts para **number|numberDecimal**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que fiz de errado, ou o que deixei de fazer? O programa nem rodou apresentou erros nas seguintes linhas:

```
l01=et01;
l02=et02;
l03=et03;

tv01.setText(l01*l02*l03);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, você deve usar o método *getText* para pegar os valores dos campos *EditText* e fazer a conversão para *Long*:

```
l01 = Long.parseLong(et01.getText().toString());
l02 = Long.parseLong(et02.getText().toString());
l03 = Long.parseLong(et03.getText().toString());
```

O método *setText* aceita um parâmetro do tipo [CharSequence](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html). Você pode fazer uma conversão para *String*:

```
tv01.setText(String.valueOf(l01 * l02 * l03));
```

Comment: O erro da última linha sumiu, obrigado! Porém ainda dá erro nas linhas onde coloco para as variáveis (l01, l02, l03) receberem os valores dos editTexts.

Comment: Desculpe, não tinha notado que havia mais erro no código. Editei a resposta com o restante do código.

Comment: Deu ruim aqui. Olha o que rolou: "close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/networkstatistics.sqlite' 
                                                 android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here" e mais "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{genesysgeneration.treerule/genesysgeneration.treerule.MainMenuActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: """